# link overhangs place css html

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem in CSS. The link overhangs his place

[image]

My code is [there](https://github.com/Botaniculus/mysite/blob/master/styl.css)

Comment: You can simply paste images directly to the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

in your css

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Yes, it has helped :-)) Thanks :D